# Autokey Loops: Performing keystrokes 10 times

Tags: loops, controls, sequence, autokey

While using Thunderbird and the Flashgot extension, I would like to download all attachments from 10 messages at a time. The sequence is ctrl-F3, enter, delete, repeat. I need 5 second pauses to allow messages to load and attachments to download. My current Autokey script doesn't work and it locks up requiring "pkill autokey". This is what I have so far, loaded as a script:

```
;Download Attachments from 10 messages and quit
Loop 10
{
  keyboard.send_key("{ctrl}{f3}")
  keyboard.send_key("{enter}")
  sleep, 5000  
  keyboard.send_key("{delete}")
  sleep, 5000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{
  keyboard.send_key("<ctrl><f3>")
  keyboard.send_key("<enter>")
  sleep, 5000  
  keyboard.send_key("<delete>")
  sleep, 5000
}
```